# Imacros: How to select from dropdown menu which is without the "content tag"

Tags: imacros

Normally when selecting an option from dropdown menu, the recorded macro look somewhat like this

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=NAME:prod ATTR=NAME:variantID_4 CONTENT=%234
```

But a website gives me this code for dropdown menu

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LI FORM=ID:enterNewOfferForm ATTR=ID:conditionSelect_chzn_o_3
```

There is no `CONTENT` tag. As a result when I play the macro, it does not select anything from the dropdown menu.

Here is the full code

```html
VERSION BUILD=10022823
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
URL GOTO=website/enterNewOffer.php
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA:TEXT FORM=ID:enterNewOfferForm ATTR=NAME:artex2Input CONTENT=Description
TAG POS=4 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:enterNewOfferForm ATTR=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=LI FORM=ID:enterNewOfferForm ATTR=ID:conditionSelect_chzn_o_3 
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:enterNewOfferForm ATTR=NAME:taxInput CONTENT=2<SP>dollar
```

I tried many variations of the code but no success

Comment: There is no ‘CONTENT’ tag because the element is ‘TYPE=LI’ (but not ‘TYPE=SELECT’). Try to record your problem line in ‘Experimental event recording mode’. And pay attention to appearing error anyway.

Comment: Hello Shugar. I get the unknown error. TypeError: details.target is null, line 8 (Error code: -1001).

Comment: Thanks! With some editing (Trimming) of the code, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Please pay the attention that you need to get a value of select tag, not of some li item.
It means that you need to use TYPE=SELECT (not TYPE=LI).

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:enterNewOfferForm ATTR=ID:conditionSelect_chzn_o_3
```

in the case if for some reason you really need to get a value of all options (li), you can extract them for future processing:

```
VERSION BUILD=1005 RECORDER=CR
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO

SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:enterNewOfferForm ATTR=ID:conditionSelect_chzn_o_3 EXTRACT=TXTALL
PROMPT {{!EXTRACT}}
```